# How to parse aggregation pipeline results?

Tags: c++, mongodb

I'm using the aggregation pipeline in C++ and after calling

```
runCommand("Database", BSON("aggregate" << "collection" << "pipeline" << pipeline), res);
```

res contains the following BSON:

```
{ waitedMS: 0, result: [ { _id: ObjectId('564ef990bfd82315fc8db2bc'), xIndex: 139 }, { _id: ObjectId('564ef990bfd82315fc8db2bd'), xIndex: 148 }, { _id
: ObjectId('564ef991bfd82315fc8db2c5'), xIndex: 139 }, { _id: ObjectId('564ef991bfd82315fc8db2c6'), xIndex: 148 }, { _id: ObjectId('564ef991bfd82315fc
8db2c7'), xIndex: 148 } ], ok: 1.0 }
```

Now, I would like to access each BSON of the result array. However, after doing

```
std::vector<BSONElement> result = res.getField("result").Array();
std::cout << result[0].toString() << std::endl;
```

I obtain the following output:

```
{ 0: { _id: ObjectId('564ef990bfd82315fc8db2bc'), xIndex: 139 } }
```

How can I obtain just a BSON `{ _id: ObjectId('564ef990bfd82315fc8db2bc'), xIndex: 139 }`?

Why mongo adds the array index?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

```
BSONObj bdoc = result[0].embeddedObject();
```

Now, `std::cout << bdoc.toString() << std::endl;` provides a more convenient output: `{ _id: ObjectId('564ef990bfd82315fc8db2bc'), xIndex: 139 }`